# Unnecessary extra margins on a multiple traces plotly chart

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am building a Plotly chart with two traces. And for some reason by default I am getting some extra space/margin between my data bars and Y axis. Here
[image]

*How to get rid of that extra space?*

If I keep only one trace, it is just fine, the bars start right from the edge. Like this
[image]

The script to reproduce the chart with two traces

```
import random
import plotly.graph_objects as go

N = 45
my_x = ['#' + str(random.randint(50, 999)) for _ in range(N)]
my_y1 = [random.randint(5, 20) for _ in range(N)]
my_y2 = [random.randint(10, 30) for _ in range(N)]

trace1 = go.Bar(name='Food',
                x=my_x,
                y=my_y1)

trace2 = go.Scatter(name='Water',
                    x=my_x,
                    y=my_y2,
                    mode='markers',
                    marker_size=12)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(trace1)
fig.add_trace(trace2)
fig.show()
```

I will appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: There may be other settings, but you can configure them below. Why is the last one set to -2, but this is a value I found manually. In the case of scatter plots, the first and last margins are automatically set, which may have an effect. `fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[-1, len(my_x)-2])`

Answer (score 2):

- the **scatter** on it's own will add the space
- make the **xaxis** continuous, define the **range** and **ticks** and the space is removed

```
import random
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

N = 45
my_x = ['#' + str(random.randint(50, 999)) for _ in range(N)]
my_y1 = [random.randint(5, 20) for _ in range(N)]
my_y2 = [random.randint(10, 30) for _ in range(N)]

trace1 = go.Bar(name='Food',
                x=np.linspace(0,N,N),
                y=my_y1)

trace2 = go.Scatter(name='Water',
                    x=np.linspace(0,N,N),
                    y=my_y2,
                    mode='markers',
                    marker_size=12)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(trace1)
fig.add_trace(trace2)
fig.update_layout(xaxis={"range":[-.5,N+.5]})
fig.update_layout(xaxis={"tickmode":"array","tickvals":np.linspace(0,N,N), "ticktext":my_x})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Rob! That works perfect!